# using ! and the in operator return false when it should be true, why?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Javascript, the following code works like so:

```
> var foo = { bar: 1 }
undefined
> foo
{ bar: 1 }
> 'bar' in foo
true
> !'bar' in foo
false
> 'baz' in foo
false
> !'baz' in foo
false
```

Why does using `!` and `in` not return `true` when checking if an object does not contain a property?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to do `!('baz' in foo)`, otherwise it's the same as `(!'baz') in foo` (which looks up `'false' in foo`), reason being operator precedence.

```
!'foo' in {false: true} //as in 'false' in {false: true}
//true

!('foo' in {false: true}) //as in, does a key "foo" not exist in the object
//true
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the `!` against the result of the  `in`

```
!("key" in object)
```

Right now it is like this.

```
(!"key") in object
```

And that is the same as doing

```
false in object
```

Whcih becomes

```
"false" in object
```